# Querying data for a given month using Realm

Tags: android, database, realm

I am using realm to store data in local.

I want to fetch data for specific month. i.e display data only for January month.

field type is Date.

In Sqllite we can do using **strftime('%m', column_name) = '05';** but in realm cound't find any solution.

Thanks.

Comment: January in a given year?

Comment: @EpicPandaForce I don't want to compare with year because I want to  display data on base of month.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set up a date for Jan 1 (year), 00:00:00:000 and a date for Feb 1 (year), 00:00:00:000 (for example with Calendar API), and use

```
RealmResults<Obj> results = realm.where(Obj.class)
        .greaterThanOrEqualTo("date", januaryDate)
        .lessThan("date", februaryDate)
        .findAllSorted("date", Sort.ASCENDING);
```

**EDIT:** Okay, querying "based on month" isn't all that simple. By default, you can only query dates like an interval of time.

You have multiple options though:

1.) build a query for all possible years for a given month between your minimum and maximum date.

```
public class Obj extends RealmObject {
    @Index
    private Date date;

    //getters, setters
}
```

Then

```
Date minimumDate = realm.where(Obj.class).minimumDate();
Date maximumDate = realm.where(Obj.class).maximumDate();
Calendar minCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
Calendar maxCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
if(minimumDate == null) {
    minimumDate = new Date();
}
if(maximumDate == null) {
    maximumDate = new Date();
}
minCalendar.setTime(minimumDate);
maxCalendar.setTime(maximumDate);
int minimumYear = minCalendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
int maximumYear = maxCalendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
Calendar transientCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
transientCalendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
transientCalendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
transientCalendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
transientCalendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
transientCalendar.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);

RealmQuery<Obj> query = realm.where(Obj.class);
boolean isFirst = true;
for(int i = minimumYear; i <= maximumYear; i++) {
   if(isFirst) {
      isFirst = false;
   } else {
      query.or();
   }
   query.beginGroup();
   transientCalendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, i);
   transientCalendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, Calendar.JANUARY);
   query.greaterThanOrEqualTo("date", transientCalendar.getTime());
   transientCalendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, Calendar.FEBRUARY);
   query.lessThan("date", transientCalendar.getTime());
   query.endGroup();
}
// then you can do
RealmResults<Obj> results = query.findAllSorted("date", Sort.ASCENDING);
```

2.) keep a field updated in your model that contains the month based on the date that you set.

```
public class Obj extends RealmObject {
    private Date date;

    @Index
    private String month;

    public String getMonth() {
        return month;
    }

    @Deprecated
    public void setMonth(String month) {
        this.month = month;
    }

    public Date getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    public void setDate(Date date) {
        this.date = date;
        if(date == null) {
            this.month = null;
        } else {
            this.month = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMMM", Locale.US).format(date);
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can do

```
RealmResults<Obj> results = realm.where(Obj.class).equalTo("month", "January").findAll();
```

Comment: I don't want to compare with year because I want to  display data on base of month.

Comment: Ah, that's not that simple. But I edited my answer for the fun of it

Comment: Thanks, @EpicPandaForce. Let me try...which is more convenient

Comment: I personally think the second one is much easier.

Comment: Yes applied second logic. but I have to do in all models where date field is there.